# Avoiding unused factor levels

Tags: r

## I want to know how to avoid following. when I viewing the data, the data are not tallying as they should be due to missing levels. what should I do?

x <- c(2, 3, 4, 4, 4)

a <- factor(x)

levels(a) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

a

Comment: Use the droplevels

Comment: Please, someone, answer my question quickly as possible.